# error creating ContentNegotiatingViewResolver in heroku spring mvc + hibernate project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, heroku

i am trying to create a view resolver in heroku mvc hibernate project here is my xml file

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="basicsInJavaBlogspot" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="basicsInJavaBlogspot.repository"></jpa:repositories>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <map>
                                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                            </map>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                            <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>




    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    </bean>

    <beans profile="default">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource"/>        
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
            <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
            <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
            <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>



</beans>
```

It end up with an error something like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager#28fe04c6' of type [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager] while setting bean property 'contentNegotiationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager#28fe04c6' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
```

my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate-template</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

                   <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.34.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0.34.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

i am using heroku spring mvc + hibernate project. The applicationContext.xml file show an error something like this "The name of the property, following JavaBean naming conventions".
i can't figure out what the problem is . Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ContentNegotiationManager` was introduced in Spring 3.2, you are using Spring 3.1.

You can either upgrade, or set up `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` in older Spring 3.1 config style. Older config style should look something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" p:favorPathExtension="true">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
             ...
        </property>
</bean>
```